# Being anonymous on the Internet

Tags: web-application, web-browser, cookies

I change my IP, and then I want to access a website with a new identity I also need to delete the cookies. Would that be enough? Are there any other ways to store information and get it back with the next request?

Comment: What is your concern/goal? being anonymous for a single site? On all sites? Answers vary from use incognito mode to use a vpn depending on your needs.

Comment: Without knowing OP's use case even Tor can be bad advice. There is no universal anonymity solution that works for all scenarios. (E.g.: If you're a whistleblower at your company but the only one using Tor, it's easy for the admins to correlate it's you despite the measures you've taken.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use the [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en).**

There are many ways besides cookies to track browsers, especially if you have Javascript enabled. The Tor browser pervents most of the more common browser fingerprinting techniques.

[This site](https://amiunique.org/faq) explains how browsers can be tracked, and has a feature to test if your browser is vulnerable.

Comment: https://panopticlick.eff.org/ is a cool little tool the EFF made that shows the ways that your specific browser allows unique identification.

Comment: @Fistbeard I was pointed to https://amiunique.org a few weeks ago, and they came to the conclusion that yes, among the users that have visited their site, I was unique.

Answer (score 4):

Along with 0x40's suggestion to use the TOR browser, I would recommend looking into booting to a secure OS such as [tails](https://tails.boum.org/). Tails uses the TOR network for all of your networking, preventing other avenues of attack.